# Facebook Permission to Explicity Share With Admin Approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-share, facebook-permissions

My question is about Facebook permission over Application Shares.
I'm developing a App solution to my Customer, out of Facebook's Domain: Here's how it works:

1. The user access a Page where he can write a message to create a post with Image features;
2. He is requested to approve this post on his Facebook's Timeline;
3. When he finishes, the post can not be instantly posted. It will be saved among other users' messages;
4. When the time comes, an administrator, through a Control Panel, will check and select the best message to qualify;
5. Only the best message will be posted on the author's Timeline (User Timeline).

The question is:

I know that Facebook is not allowing Implicit Shares, but I don't know if posting only after an administrator input is considered implicit, because there won't be user approval on that moment. He already did it back there writing the message.

Is that possible, or I will have to make another request through Notification or something?

Comment: Are you posting on users timeline or a page timeline?

Comment: Hey @WizKid. It's on Users' Timeline.

Comment: Why do someone need to approve what the user post on their on wall?

Comment: _“an administrator […] will check and select the best message to qualify”_ – qualify for what exactly?

Comment: It's because it works like a contest. Various Users will write messages with imaging features, but only the best one will be qualified to be posted on Facebook. The others won't be posted.

Comment: You are not allowed to have users participate in any contests by having them make posts to their own timeline. At most, you are allowed to let them post/comment onto a Facebook page to enter any kind of competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments. Here's the answer to my own question:

The Answer is NO. Doing a post without user confirmation, even if he already did it some time ago is considered a Implicit Share, and it is no longer possible. There is another problem with the step I provided. You cannot ask for a user to publish something that won't be made instantly. If you ask to do this, it must be right on time. I think there is an exception for Pages, but that's not the point.

To comply with facebook's policy, the same functionality can be made with these steps:

1. The user access a Page where he can write a message to create a post with Image features;
2. At this moment The User is NOT asked to post this on Facebook. He is just asked to create it without mentioning Facebook itself;
3. When he finishes, the post will be saved among other users' messages;
4. When the time comes, an administrator, through a Control Panel, will check and select the best message to qualify and notify the selected user to access the link containing the message;
5. Here, finally, the user can see his message and is asked to post it into his timeline;

The applications must always do exactly what they tell the Users they are going to do, and you cannot ask something or request a permission for some functionality that you won't use at that moment.

Thank you!